# How do I get the web site's root URL from a Quartz.NET job?

Tags: asp.net, quartz.net

I am implementing a scheduler with Quartz.NET in an ASP.NET web project. The web site is purely there to house some WCF services that form the back-end of a WPF desktop application. Therefore, the web site will only be active when the users of the desktop application are active. This means that the web site application is likely to close down during the night. However, I want the scheduler to keep running at all times.

Note that using a Windows service isn't an option due to our hosting, even though that would seem to be the best option overall. I am stuck with something like Quartz.NET (as far as I know).

Whilst reading around about this, I have seen a lot of suggestions to use a scheduled job that calls a page on the site every 19 minutes, to avoid the 20 minute time out. First question is, is this the best way to do it?

If it is, then I have a second question. All of the examples I have seen show a hard-coded URL, which I want to avoid. Ideally, I want the URL to be picked up in code, so that when running in Visual Studio, it will pick up and call the `localhost` URL, and when deployed, it will pick up the live one.

I know I can put the URL in the web.config file, and use a transform to change this to the live one when deploying, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This guy seems to have thought it out well:

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net

I will paste the header paragraph here, in case the link above dies.  Then future readers have some piece of concrete info to search on.

```
A perennial question on the ASP.NET forums concerns how to schedule regular tasks as part of a web application. Typically, the requirement is to send emails once every 24 hours at a particular time each day, but it could actually be anything from tweeting on a schedule to performing maintenance tasks. Equally typically, half a dozen members on the forum dive in with recommendations to install Windows Services or schedule batch files with the Task Scheduler - regardless of the fact that most web site owners are not afforded such privileges as part of their shared hosting plan.
```

The above URL, I got from the below.

Since you cannot write a windows-service, then look at this url.  It has some options.

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure how it answers my question. The first link was the main one I used when I started with Quartz.NET, and is a great introduction, but doesn't cover my question. As for the second link, it's good reading (as he always is), but again, doesn't answer my question. It gives various options for setting up scheduled jobs, but as we're already committed to Quartz.NET, we don't want to switch now. Not that switching would help, as we'd still have the same question of finding the root URL of the web site holding the scheduler. What did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that the answer is quite simple. The job itself doesn't know anything about the web context, but the containing application does.

All I needed to do was add a static string property to the job that pings the web site...

```
public static string WebSiteRootUrl = "";
```

...then in the Global.asax.cs of the ASP.NET web project, I did the following...

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (KeepWebSiteAliveJob.WebSiteRootUrl == "") {
        string uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        KeepWebSiteAliveJob.WebSiteRootUrl = uri.Substring(0, uri.IndexOf("/", 8) + 1);
      }
    }
```

As the Request object isn't available when the application starts, I had to do this in Application_BeginRequest, which means that a) it will be fired every time a request is made and  b) the URL returned by `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` will include the full path to the requested resource, not just the desired root URL.

To get around the first issue, I only set `KeepWebSiteAliveJob.WebSiteRootUrl` if is hasn't been set yet (ie is an empty string) This will be on the very first request. I don't think this would actually be an issue without the check, as it's so quick that it is unlikely to cause any problems, but it was an easy check, so worth including just in case.

As for the second issue, I took advantage of the fact that an URL will contain two forward slashes between the scheme and the domain, and then a third after the domain and (optional) port. As we are only using http or https for the scheme, the magic number 8 starts the IndexOf() search after the double slashes, meaning that we get back the root URL.

Hope this helps someone.